# Split fields tab by tab using C++

Tags: c++, string, ifstream, getline

Given a text file just like (file.txt):

> 1234567A (THIS IS TAB) Peter, ABC (THIS IS TAB) 23523456
>   1345678A (THIS IS TAB) Michael CDE (THIS IS TAB) 23246756
>   1299283A (THIS IS TAB) Andy (THIS IS TAB) 98458388

```
ifstream inFile;
string s;
string id;
string name;
int phoneNo;
inFile.open("file.txt");
while (!inFile.eof()) {
   getline(inFile, s, '\t');
}
```

How can I extract a string of a line into different fields? For example, when I print `s`, it gives `1234567A`. I have tried some techniques found in Stackoverflow, however, I cannot achieve the goal.

Thanks.

---

One more thing I want to ask is if the third field (i.e. `phoneNo`) consists of 1-3 elements,

> 1234567A (THIS IS TAB) Peter, ABC (THIS IS TAB) 23523456 (THIS IS TAB) 12312312
>   1345678A (THIS IS TAB) Michael CDE (THIS IS TAB) 23246756
>   1299283A (THIS IS TAB) Andy (THIS IS TAB) 98458388 (THIS IS TAB) 123123123 (THIS IS TAB) 123123123

How can I distinguish the number of `phoneNo`?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


//...

std::ifstream inFile( "file.txt" );

std::string record;

while ( std::getline( inFile, record ) )
{ 
   std::istringstream is( record );

   std::string id;
   std::string name;
   int phoneNo = 0;

   is >> id >> name >> phoneNo; 
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


//...

std::ifstream inFile( "file.txt" );

std::string record;

while ( std::getline( inFile, record ) )
{
   if ( record.find_first_not_of( " \t" ) == std::string::npos ) continue;

   std::istringstream is( record );

   std::string id;
   std::string name;
   int phoneNo = 0;

   is >> id >> name >> phoneNo; 
}
```

If for example field name consists from several words when instead of the `operator >>` you should use again function `std::getline` For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


//...

std::ifstream inFile( "file.txt" );

std::string record;

while ( std::getline( inFile, record ) )
{
   if ( record.find_first_not_of( " \t" ) == std::string::npos ) continue;

   std::istringstream is( record );

   std::string id;
   std::string name;
   int phoneNo = 0;

   std::getline( is, id, '\t' );
   std::getline( is, name, '\t' );
   is >> phoneNo; 
}
```

If the number of phones cna be variable you should either use `std::vector<unsigned int>` or `std::vector<std::string>` and change the last statement of the function I showed the following way

```
   while ( is >> phoneNo ) v.push_back( phoneNo );
```

where v can be defined for example as `std::vector<unsigned int>`

Comment: if the cotent of name is  "Peter ABC"
it cannot cout the correct name... how can solve it?

Comment: with reference to the bold problem, how can i solve it?
i tested it using `if phoneNo2==" ")....` but it doesn't work